# NodeJS: callbacks inside promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am logging in two different services and I need to push both responses to an array. For that, I am creating a `promiseResult`, and inside it, two other promises for the logins:

```
var promiseResult = new Promise(function(resolveResult, rejectResult) {
  var dataAvailable = []
  // first promise for the first login
  var promiseFirstLogin = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    login.returnData(email, password, (dataFirstLogin) => {
      resolve(dataFirstLogin)
    })
  })
  promiseFirstLogin.then(function(dataFirstLogin) {
    return dataFirstLogin
  })
  .then(function(dataFirstLogin) {
    // pushing the data of the first login
    dataAvailable.push({dataFirstLogin: dataFirstLogin})
    return dataAvailable
  })

  // if the user puts the login for the second service
  if (second_login_username) {
    // second promise of the second login
    var promiseSecondLogin = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      login.returnSecondData(secondUsername, secondPassword, (secondData) => {
        resolve(secondData)
      })
    })
    promiseSecondLogin.then(function(secondData) {
      return secondData
    })
    .then(function(secondData) {
      // pushing second data to the same array
      dataAvailable.push({secondData: secondData})
      return dataAvailable
    })
  }
  // logs undefined (?)
  console.log('->', dataAvailable);
  /* 
  I try to resolve the array with my data, but it needs to be inside the promises. 
  However, as I have multiple data sources, I cannot simply put the resolve function 
  inside each promise. How to proceed with this? 
  */
  resolveResult(dataAvailable)
})
promiseResult.then(function (dataAvailable) {
  // I try to get the array with my data... but unsuccessfully 
  return dataAvailable
})
.then(function (dataAvailable) {
  dataAvailable.reduce(function(result, item) {
    var key = Object.keys(item)[0]
    result[key] = item[key];
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result, null, 3));
  }, {})
})
```

As I wrote in the comments, I try to `resolve()` the array with the data from both logins, but it needs to be inside the promises. However, I have multiple data sources, and I cannot simply put the `resolve()` inside each promise. How to put one single `resolve()` containing both of my services' data?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I did not understand the reason of the downvote. Please, let me know how  I can improve my question.

Comment: Did you check my answer? That's what you need to do.

Comment: Yes, I did -- I really appreciated it and upvoted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an array of promises. If the user adds login info for the 2nd service add that promise to the array.

Then, use
 `Promise.all(yourPromiseArray).then((values)=>{
  //All promises are resolved. Do something with the values array
})`

Comment: Worked perfectly!